# Pegar dados de usuário do JSON por jquery

Tags: javascript, json, rest, restful, cross-browser

Tenho um json que estou executando através do json-server e esta no endereço: http://localhost:3000/

Dentro dele, tem um escopo de "users", na qual eu gostaria de pegar.

Eu tenho o seguinte script que montei, segue:

```
$.getJSON(urlParam, function (data) {
        let itens = []
        $.each( data, function (key, val) {
            itens.push( {key, val} )
        })
        return itens
})
```

Eu gostaria de pegar tanto uma lista de usuários, que seja convertida para json, tanto um usuário apenas.

Segue meu json:

```
{
  "alunos": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nome": "Thiago Cunha"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "nome": "Caroline Cunha"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "nome": "Thalita Cunha"
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nome": "Thiago Cunha",
      "img": "dist/images/thiago.jpg",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "nome": "Caroline Cunha",
      "img": "dist/images/thiago.jpg",
      "status": true
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "nome": "Thalita Cunha",
      "img": "dist/images/thiago.jpg",
      "status": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Comment: está um pouco confusa sua pergunta. Para pegar os usuários não precisa converter nada, seria `var usuarios = data.users`, agora para pegar um único usuário pode fazer uma *function* que pesquise no array por um parâmetro, `id` por exemplo, algo assim: `let usuario = usuarios.find(o => o.id === parametroId);`

Comment: NA minha humilde opinião você poderia criar um endpoint diferente para buscar o registro individual do usuário, ficando um para a busca do usuário e outro para todos os usuários. Por Exemplo: url /users para todos os usuários e a url /user/id  (onde id é a chave primária ou identificador do usuário) para o registro individual do usuário.

Answer (score 1):

Na minha humilde opinião você poderia criar um endpoint diferente para buscar o registro individual do usuário, ficando um para a busca do usuário e outro para todos os usuários. 
Por Exemplo: url `/users` para todos os usuários e a url `/user/id`  (onde `id` é a chave primária ou identificador do usuário) para o registro individual do usuário.

Comment: Eu já fiz isso. Como o sistema de backend é jsp, eu acabo usando uma regra de URL definido pelo servlets aqui da empresa que eu trabalho. Mas a ideia é boa e funciona aqui.